# How can I bind the schematic variable ?case in a rule for proof by cases?

Tags: proof, isabelle

I would like to define a rule for proof by cases, to be used with `proof (cases rule: <rule-name>)`.  I managed to use the `case_names` and `consumes` parameters, but I did not manage to bind the schematic variable `?case`, so that, inside a case of a proof using my rule, one can write `show ?case ...`.  How do I bind it?

Concretely: I have the Mizar-inspired notion of a *trivial set*, i.e. empty or singleton set. I would like to prove properties of trivial sets by *empty* vs. *singleton* case analysis. So far I have:

```
definition trivial where "trivial x = (x ⊆ {the_elem x})"

lemma trivial_cases [case_names empty singleton, consumes 1]:
  assumes "trivial X"
  assumes empty: "P {}"
      and singleton: "⋀ x . X = {x} ⟹ P {x}"
  shows "P X"
using assms unfolding trivial_def by (metis subset_singletonD)
```

and I can make use of this as follows:

```
notepad
begin
  fix Q
  fix X::"'a set"
  have "trivial X" sorry
  then have "Q X"
  proof (cases rule: trivial_cases)
    case empty
    show "Q {}" sorry
  next
    case (singleton x)
    show "Q {x}" sorry
  qed
end
```

But I cannot use `show ?case`.  If I try, it gives me the error message "Unbound schematic variable: ?case".  `print_cases` inside the proof outputs the following:

```
cases:
  empty:
    let "?case" = "?P {}"
  singleton:
    fix x_
    let "?case" = "?P {x_}"
    assume "X = {x_}"
```

Which suggests that it doesn't work because `?P` is not bound to `trivial`.

*BTW:* The full context in which I am using this can be seen at https://github.com/formare/auctions/blob/master/isabelle/Auction/SetUtils.thy.

Comment: `cases` AFAIK never binds `?case`. Maybe you want to use the `induct` method, which does?

Comment: Thanks, that works.  I just hadn't thought of trying it, as using “induction” to prove a finite statement seemed strange to me.  And indeed a different pattern has been suggested here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Joachim already mentioned, unlike `induct`, the `cases` method does not bind the schematic variable `?case`. I would say the "canonical" way of conducting *case analysis* (as a proof method) conforms to this setup, since typically only different assumptions -- which taken together are exhaustive -- are considered, whereas the conclusion stays the same (abbreviated by `?thesis` in Isabelle) throughout the different cases. I would set up your `trivial_cases` as follows:

```
lemma trivial_cases [consumes 1, case_names empty singleton]:
  assumes "trivial X" and "X = {} ⟹ P" and "⋀x . X = {x} ⟹ P"
  shows "P"
  using assms by (auto simp: trivial_def)
```

Then you can use it like

```
notepad
begin
  fix P and X :: "'a set"
  have "trivial X" sorry
  then have "P X"
  proof (cases rule: trivial_cases)
    case empty
    then show ?thesis sorry
  next
    case (singleton x)
    then show ?thesis sorry
  qed
end
```

where the simplifier or explicit unfolding takes care of specializing `X` to `{}` and `{x}`, respectively.

**Side Note:** You can further tune `trivial_cases` by adding the attribtue `cases pred: trivial`. Then, whenever `trivial ?X` is the major assumption fed to `cases`, the rule `trivial_cases` is used implicitly, i.e., you can do the following

```
have "trivial X" sorry
then have "P X"
proof (cases)
```

in the above proof.

Comment: Thanks, that works very well.  I have now modified my sources accordingly.  `cases pred` actually also allows me to get rid of `consumes 1`, as the latter is the default for `cases pred` (`isabelle doc isar-ref` section 6.6.3).

Comment: Although the feature to enable `proof induct` and `proof cases` without a rule is very slick I have later regretted using it, when I was reading my theories a few months later. Explicit rules are more stable!

Comment: Good point.  However if Isabelle supported (I think it doesn't) displaying what implicit rule it applied whenever you write `proof` or `proof (cases)` or `proof (induct)` without explicitly referencing a rule, this would be easier to manage.

Comment: @JoachimBreitner: I kind of disagree ;). If I have an explicit rule, the only additional information (at least at this point in the sources) I get is the name of the rule, which might be completely useless. A combination of implicit rules and explicitly stating assumptions (instead of using `case (...)`) is the most *readable* variant I think. The cost is that you have to type more and maybe duplicate some formulas. (But of course I see the value of being able to click on a rule name and get to the corresponding proof.)

Comment: I agree with @ChristophLange: It would be all fine if `proof`, `proof cases` et. al. would tell me what they are doing.

Comment: @JoachimBreitner I think you can declare [[rule_trace]] to get more information from rule et al.